# Same R history from different workspace

Tags: r, rstudio

I am new to R and I just figured out why my history did not contain all my previous commands. R create a .Rhistory file in each working directory.

I often change working directory and I would like to have the history of all my past sessions in the same file. Is there a simple way to do that ?

Thanks.
(I am on Mac OS 10.6 and I use Rstudio)

Comment: Please read the example provided at the end of `?savehistory`.

Comment: Pretty much no moderately experienced R user saves their history. I would urge you to start writing scripts, which then contain your commands and can be rerun easily. You can use Rgui for this, but it is much more convenient to use RStudio.

Comment: @Roland. I have used matlab for years, and I definitely used functions, scripts, but also history. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to manually save your history like this:

```
savehistory(file = "~/.Rhistory")
```

and then load it when you open an R command session:

```
loadhistory(file = "~/.Rhistory")
```

Otherwise you can edit your 'Rprofile.site' and add `savehistory()` and `loadhistory()` to the functions `.Last` and `.First` respectively.

More info about `Rprofile.site`: [here](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html)

> At startup, R will source the Rprofile.site file. It will then look for a .Rprofile file to source in the current working directory. If it doesn't find it, it will look for one in the user's home directory. There are two special functions you can place in these files. .First( ) will be run at the start of the R session and .Last( ) will be run at the end of the session.

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not work. I tried to create .Rprofile, and .Rprofile.site. The R.profile is well loaded at start up. However, it doesn't save the history in the good folder (even if the same command works when it is executed directly in R).

Comment: I have made several attempts, for instance:          .First<- function(){
     if(interactive()) try(loadhistory("~/.Rhistory"))
}

.Last <- function(){
    if(interactive()) try(savehistory("~/.Rhistory"))
}

Comment: If you run R using `R --no-save --no-restore-data --quiet`, does it work then?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I use Rstudio